# Problem with the data

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the problem with the data in my database.
I tried to put some data and show it on my spinner. But I have the empty spinner.
I really don't understand where I was wrong.
Here is my code

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+colCountryID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "+
            colCountryName+ " TEXT)");
    InsertCountry(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public Cursor getAllDepts() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + colCountryID + " as _id, " + colCountryName + " from " + TABLE_NAME, new String[] {});
    return cur;
}

public void InsertCountry(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(colCountryID, 1);
    cv.put(colCountryName, "GB");
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    Log.w(TABLE_NAME, "insert");

}
```

And

```
database = new DBTestHelper(this);

Cursor c=database.getAllDepts();
startManagingCursor(c);


SimpleCursorAdapter ca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.dvdfg, c, new String [] {DBTestHelper.colCountryName,"_id"}, new int []{R.id.text});
//ca.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
counry.setAdapter(ca);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + colCountryID + " as _id, " + colCountryName + " from " + TABLE_NAME, new String[] {});
```

seems strange to me try to pass a null array as last argument

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + colCountryID + " as _id, " + colCountryName + " from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
```

Comment: did you try reading the cursor by yourself instead of letting the spinner do it. Loop through your cursor in getAllDepts.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand you.Could you explain in more details?

Comment: And System.out.println the return of your inserts to see if they worked.

Comment: cursor.moveToFirst();

While( !cursor.isAfterLast() )
{
  //print data
}//while

Comment: I shoul delete public Cursor getAllDepts() in my DBTestHelper.class and add something like this in Activity class?Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(""SELECT " + colCountryID + " as _id, " + colCountryName + " from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
  while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

Comment: Sorry for my maybe stupid question. It's really hard for me to understand how it works.

Comment: I've changed

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + DBTestHelper.colCountryID + " as _id, " + DBTestHelper.colCountryName + " from " + DBTestHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);
  ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   items.add(cursor.getString(0));
   items.add(cursor.getString(1));

   ArrayAdapter ca = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
   counry.setAdapter(ca);

But i received 1 and GB in my spinner.
Why?